# How do I create an "addons" directory in a Django project?

Tags: django

When building a Django project its common to use many pre-built apps. For example, for tinymce or open-id.

It would be nice to keep these separated from project-specific apps.

My idea would be to create an "addons" directory/module in the project.

It should then be possible to use:

```
from addons.tinymce import models
```

However, tinymce's code uses, eg:

```
from tinymce import models
```

So my solution would be to add "addons" to sys.path in settings.py:

```
import sys, os
sys.path = [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'addons')] + sys.path
```

Does all that seem sensible? Is there a better way?

Comment: Just add it to your Python path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can arange your addons however you like. All you need to do is to add the addons folder to your python path. That way you can still just do

```
from tinymce import models
```

but your addons will be organized. A project is no more than a folder added to your python path anyways.